# Reading from file in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to read from a file in Haskell, and i'm having trouble handling the data afterwards.

Basically, what i want to do is, read the file, and then create a matrix based on the data that was read. 
But it is a bit trickier than this. I'll explain:

Here's an example input file:

```
6 - number of lines in the matrix
7 - number of columns in the matrix
PA 3123
PB 11254
PC 790
PD 86214        
PE 114125
PF 36214
```

and the rest is the data itself.

Now, since in this example,the number of columns is seven, the matrix must be created the following way:

```
 Column 1  | Column 2  |  Column 3  |  Column 4 |  Column 5  |  Column 6  |  Column 7 

 3123/1       3123/2       3123/3       3123/4      3123/5       3123/6       3123/7

  ...          ...          ...          ...         ...          ...           ...
```

and the same for the others.

I've search the site for answers, and i've read some parts of the book [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), and i was able to come up with this code:

```
-- Imports needed
import System.IO
import Data.List
import Data.Text


-- Runs the program
main = do
    putStrLn "Please insert the name of the file you want to process:"
    file <- getLine
    read_File file


-- Reads all file content
read_File file = do
h <- openFile file ReadMode
content <- hGetContents h
hClose h
handleFile content

-- Handles the content of the file
handleFile content = do
n1 <- getLine 
n2 <- getLine
-- here comes my big problem, how can i create the matrix properly?
putStrLn n1
putStrLn n2
```

This code compiles just fine, but there is an issue. I've put two putStrLn at the end, to verify that the file was properly read, but when i run it, i get no errors, but no data at all.

Thanks in advance!

PS: Here's the compilation process!

[image: Compilation Process]

Comment: What command are you using to run this code? I get `test.hs:22:20: parse error on input ‘=’` when doing `runhaskell test.hs`

Comment: i use GHCI, ":l test.hs" and i don't get any error @MaxGabriel

Comment: @MaxGabriel i've edited it with an image from the command prompt

Comment: The formatting of your `read_File` and `handleFile` functions is incorrect; you need to indent the body of your `do` constructs.  Haskell questions, particularly, need to be properly formatted as many questions are about incorrect parses caused by improper formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

First, `handleFile` is reading from stdin - it should process the data in `content`:

```
handleFile content = do
  let lns = Prelude.lines content
      (n1:n2:rest) = lns  -- first two lines
  putStrLn $ "first line is: " ++ n1
  putStrLn $ "second line is: " ++ n2
```

Second, this is going to be a problem:

```
...
h <- openFile file ReadMode
content <- hGetContents h
hClose h
handleFile content
...
```

`hGetContents` uses lazy I/O - data is not read until it is needed. By performing `hClose h` you will be closing the file handle before any data is read.

You can fix this by performing the `hClose` after performing `handleFile`, e.g.:

```
content <- hGetContents h
handleFile content
hClose h
```

Alternatively, you can use `readFile` and not worry about opening or closing the file:

```
content <- readFile file
```

Comment: it does not work only with the readFile option. Thank you! Can you now give some guidance on the matrix problem ?

Comment: another problem i spoted, is that, in your version, after the first two numbers the 'rest' seems to be empty, because when i try to print it out, it does not print anything...

Comment: Here is my code: http://lpaste.net/114404 Post your code and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I get a type check error on line 25. Note that `rest` is a list of Strings, not a single String. Just use `print rest` to see what it looks like (use a small input file.)

Comment: can you give some hints, on how to create the matrix properly ?

Comment: If you can write the program in another language, we can help you translate it into Haskell.

Comment: http://lpaste.net/114411 here it is the code in java. I've been following this to translate the program into Haskell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65049/discussion-between-dcarou-and-user5402).